# Equivalent of Select Where In with Outlook DASL Filter

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, advanced-search

I am searching a list of mails from their respective *PR_MESSAGE_ID* using the Outlook VSTO [AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866933.aspx) feature.

My query looks like

```
 http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E = 'targetId1' OR
 http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E = 'targetId2' OR
 http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E = 'targetId3' OR 
 http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E = 'targgetId4' ...etc.
```

I am questioning the performance of this approach and I would like to know if there is a more elegant query, similar to a *SELECT something WHERE 'MESSAGE_ID' IN (targetId1, targetId2, etc.)*

Answer (score 0):

No, AdvancedSearch is a right choise because the search is performed in the background not blocking the UI thread. Moreover, you can search for items in multiple forlders.

All DASL queries begin with a case-sensitive prefix "@SQL=", with the exception of DASL queries for [Application.AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933.aspx).

See [Filtering Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863965.aspx) for other alternatives.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, sorry if it was not clear. I edited the question. Actually, I am not looking for another search approach but another DASL query to pass to the AdvancedSearch method.

Comment: See [Filtering Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863965.aspx) for other alternatives.

Comment: I already looked to this ressource. I do not see any 'contains' or 'in' operator.

Comment: IN is not supported simply because there is no such restriction on the MAPI level - it only exposes RES_OR restriction, which is functionally exactly the same.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko so my query is the best that I can achieve to retrieve a list of emails?

Comment: Yes. An OR query is the best you can do.